# решение алгоритмической задачки с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться, как с помощью JavaScript правильно решить следующую задачу:

"Под Новый год у Деда Мороза остается ограниченное количество подарков.
Ниже приведен список детей, которые написали письмо Деду Морозу с просьбами о новогодних подарках, а также какие именно 
подарки они хотят.

Учитывая, что у Деда Мороза имеется только по **ОДНОЙ ЕДИНИЦЕ** каждого подарка и что каждому ребенку нужен подарок, который он попросил в письме, какой подарок следует подарить Маше?"

Comment: Да итеративно. Суём первому первый подарок из его списка. Затем второму первый подарок из его списка... дошли до очередного, и нет совпадений списка и оставшихся подарков? на шаг назад и там вместо первого даём второй. Дошли до конца списка? выводим вариант раздачи и шаг назад. Перебрали все варианты текущего ребёнка? шаг назад? некуда назад? перебор окончен.

Comment: Hint. Если есть подарок, упомянутый во всех списках один раз - отдать и выбросить из рассмотрения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не алгоритм, но Маше повезло больше всех - **Макбук**

```js
const DM = {
  Ваня: ['Наушники', 'Смартфон', 'Лего', 'Трансформер', 'Велосипед'],
  Лена: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Айпод'],
  Денис: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Айпод'],
  Петя: ['Смартфон', 'Айпод'],
  Вася: ['Наушники', 'Лего', 'Самокат', 'Макбук', 'Велосипед'],
  Маша: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Макбук', 'Айпод'],
  Гоша: ['Наушники', 'Лего', 'Айпод', 'Велосипед', 'Макбук'],
}

const storage = []
const arrSort = Object.entries(DM).sort((a, b) => a[1].length - b[1].length)
const NP = {}
arrSort.forEach((i) => {
  let p = i[1].findIndex((q) => !storage.includes(q))
  if (p === -1) {
    throw 'Нет подарка'
  }
  p = i[1][p]
  storage.push(p)
  NP[i[0]] = p
});
console.log(NP)
```

**UPD: Решил исправить** на надежный вариант.

```js
const DM = {
  Ваня: ['Наушники', 'Смартфон', 'Лего', 'Трансформер', 'Велосипед'],
  Лена: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Айпод'],
  Денис: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Айпод'],
  Петя: ['Смартфон', 'Айпод'],
  Вася: ['Наушники', 'Лего', 'Самокат', 'Макбук', 'Велосипед'],
  Маша: ['Смартфон', 'Самокат', 'Макбук', 'Айпод'],
  Гоша: ['Наушники', 'Лего', 'Айпод', 'Велосипед', 'Макбук'],
  // Для проверки
  Тетя_Валя: ['Трансформер', 'Велосипед', 'Наушники', 'Лего', 'Макбук', 'Самокат', 'Смартфон', 'Айпод'],
  Mне: ['Трансформер', 'Велосипед', 'Наушники', 'Лего', 'Макбук', 'Самокат', 'Смартфон', 'Айпод']
}

const present = {}
const happy = {}

// Разворачиваем объект {подарок:[...желающие]}
for (const [name, list] of Object.entries(DM)) {
  list.forEach((p) => {
    present[p] ? present[p].push(name) : (present[p] = [name])
  })
}

// Сортируем по наименьшему желанию 
//  => [подарок_1:[меньше_детей] ... подарок_N[...больше]]
// ... и Раздаем
Object.entries(present)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1].length - b[1].length)
  .forEach(([p, names]) => {

    // Отбрасываем тех, кто получил
    let min = Infinity
    let chn
    let chlds = names.filter((n) => (
      !happy[n] &&
      // ... и сразу находим ребенка с наименьшим остатком вариантов
      (min > DM[n].length ? (chn = n, min = DM[n].length) : true)
    ))

    // Если дети (для этого подарка) закончились
    if (!chn /* or !chlds.length*/) return

    // Дарим
    happy[chn] = p

    // Оставляем тех кто еще не получил
    chlds.splice(chlds.indexOf(chn), 1)
    // ... и удаляем (только у них) все варианты этого подарка 
    // ... чтоб выше использовать DM[n].length
    chlds.forEach((n) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < DM[n].length; ++i) {
        (DM[n][i] === p) && DM[n].splice(i--, 1)
      }
    })
  })

// Самые несчастные дети
Object.keys(DM)
  .filter((n) => !happy[n])
  .forEach((n) => happy[n] = 'Твой папа не заплатил(c)ДМ')

console.log(happy)
```

**PS**: Смешно, но Маша опять самая везучая, а Лена как всегда на самокате.

Comment: Alexander Lonberg , спасибо Вам большое за Ваше время и помощь. Не очень понимаю, почему используется индекс 1 при сортировании массива и  итерации с forEach? 
То есть здесь: `const arrSort = Object.entries(DM).sort((a, b) => a[1].length - b[1].length)`
И здесь:  `let p = i[1].findIndex((q) => !storage.includes(q))`

Comment: @ellen потому что мы сортируем не массив, а объект приведенный к массиву, где элемент `1` - это и есть массивы подарков длину которых я и отсортировал - отдаем первый подарок самому скромнику, у кого наименьший массив. И движемся к тем у кого больше вариантов выбора. _PS. Ленку мне тоже жалко - опять как дура весь год на самокате кататься будет._

Comment: теперь поняла, спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Я бы на месте Деда Мороза первым делом выдал бы Ване трансформер, а уж потом стал бы разбираться с остальными детьми. :)

Comment: @Yaant :) я только сейчас заметил. Трансформер то Дед себе оставил

Comment: @ellen возьмите лучше этот вариант, первый на деле работать не будет

Comment: @Yaant так и не смог спокойно смотреть на Ваню. Взял и все исправил.

Comment: самое интересное, что это в уме решается. Лена + Денис + Петя забирают гарантированно 3 подарка (понятно каких) и у Маши остаётся только 1 вариант.

Comment: @pavel так задача то не для решения, а для алгоритма, который может пересчитать тысячи детей

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, спасибо Вам большое, все учту:)